# Fullpage.js disable on mobile/below given pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, fullpage.js

https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

I've tried code like this but that doesn't work sadly. I want to disable it after 976px for mobile users.

```
<script>
if (screen && screen.width > 768) {
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://your-file-path/fullpage.js"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `responsiveWidth` or `responsiveHeight` option combined with `fp-auto-height-responsive`.

Read more about all of those options in [the fullPage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) or see [this codepen](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/MzByMa).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code after the one you are using, e.g.:

```
<script>
 if (screen && screen.width > 768) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://your-file-path/fullpage.js"><\/script>');
 }
</script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage();
 });
</script>
```

This script is especially useful if your are using Webflow since sometimes script won’t work as intended without firing them first.

I had the same situation, but the script above worked for me!